# not able to receive axios data sent via post method at my backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

so i am using react js as my front-end framework and node and express js for my back end .
i used axios to send data from my react app to my back end server but am not able to receive the data at my server end.

my react js code to send data

```
function handelClick(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    
    console.log(data);
    axios.post("http://localhost:9000/login",data)
    .then(response=>console.log(response))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err));
}
```

my node js server side code to receive data

```
app.post('/login',(req,res)=>{console.log(req);});
```

i thought i could find the sent data inside req object but i don't see it .
am new so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: can you confirm the request is being sent by your `handleClick` function? Are there any logs/errors in the console? can you post from Postman or curl to your `localhost:9000/login` endpoint?

Comment: @LostJon whenever i click the submit button i get a request object at my server side console . So that means that request is sent , the req object contains all the header and routes and other element but i dont see my sent data these

Comment: @LostJon for general , how can we normally get the data sent by axios post method at my server side

Comment: Did you set up the cors and JSON parser middlewares in the node application main file?

Comment: @LucaPizzini thank you for the response ,i had my cors up but i didn't had my JSON parser set up i fixed it  and now its working . Thank you every one .

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported axios in reactjs file? Or you can try to check in package.json of reactjs app had:

```
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000" //port running on your server
```

Comment: I have already imported axios the issue was server side I didn't had my express.json set up . I solved it now . Thanks for you input